# Why $\sigma (X^2)\subsetneq \sigma (X)$ where $X$ is a r.v.?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ a r.v. In my lecture, it's written that $\sigma (X^2)\subsetneq \sigma (X)$. The inclusion is clear. But why is the inclusion strict ? Indeed, let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt {|x|}&x\geq 0\\ -\sqrt{|x|}&x<0\end{cases}.$$
It's clear that $f$ is continuous (thus Borelien), and that $X=f(X^2)$. Therefore $X\in \sigma (X^2)$. What's wrong here ?

Comment: Your equality is false. Is $-1=f(1)$?

Comment: your function $x\mapsto f(x^2)$ is not well defined.

Comment: Actually the two sigma algebras may be equal: Take $X=1$. But in general you have strict inclusion as seen by taking $\pm1$ valued random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (measurable or otherwise) such that $f(x^2) = x,$ as this would mean
$$-1 = f((-1)^2) = f(1) = f(1^2) = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y\equiv X^2$. If $X(\Omega)\cap \mathbb{R}_{<0}\ne \emptyset$, then $Y^{-1}(-\infty,0)=\emptyset\ne X^{-1}(-\infty,0)$.